# Bootstrap 4 elements don't align when added div

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

How it should look

[image]

How it is not suppose to look

[image]
So my goal is to try to make my Registration form look like my login form. All I did was added extra fields and then the form went crazy. Can anyone explain? I searched the internet for help but that didn't work and I was just really trying to make this one work because it looks nice. Yes I am working and learning dJango so I just wanted this to look nice even though it is not even needed. I go the extra mile sometimes but hate when I don't understand.

This is my index html and login form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" />

    <title>Albert's Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="Form my-4 mx-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <img
              src="../static/img/swordandshield.jpg"
              alt=""
              class="img-fluid"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7 px-5 pt-5">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold py3">Welcome to My place</h1>
            <h4>Sign into your account</h4>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>User Name</h4>
                  <input
                    type="userName"
                    name="userName"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>Password</h4>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    name="pw"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <button class="btn1 mt-3 mb-5" type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <p>
                Don't have an account yet?<a href="/register">Register here</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my registration form, it uses the same css and boostrap method

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" />

    <title>Albert's Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="Form my-4 mx-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <img
              src="../static/img/swordandshield.jpg"
              alt=""
              class="img-fluid"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7 px-5 pt-5">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold py3">Registration Form</h1>
            <h4>Sign up for an account</h4>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>Your Full Name</h4>
                  <input
                    type="fullName"
                    name="fullName"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>User Name</h4>
                  <input
                    type="userName"
                    name="userName"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>Password</h4>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    name="pw"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>Confirm Password</h4>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    name="cpw"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <button class="btn1 mt-3 mb-5" type="submit">Register</button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <p>Have an account then <a href="/">Sign In</a></p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my css

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: rgb(211, 218, 218);
}
.row {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 22px;
}
img {
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}
.btn1 {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.btn1:hover {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(51, 105, 38);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: rgb(211, 218, 218);
}
.row {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 22px;
}
img {
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}
.btn1 {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.btn1:hover {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(51, 105, 38);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" />

    <title>Albert's Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="Form my-4 mx-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602900004353-2e786ce8f35c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=658&q=80"
              alt=""
              class="img-fluid"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7 px-5 pt-5">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold py3">Registration Form</h1>
            <h4>Sign up for an account</h4>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>Your Full Name</h4>
                  <input
                    type="fullName"
                    name="fullName"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
              <!-- I added below </div> tag here. only one change and it works. -->
              </div>
              <!-- Change Ended. -->                    
                <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>User Name</h4>
                  <input
                    type="userName"
                    name="userName"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>Password</h4>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    name="pw"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <h4>Confirm Password</h4>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    name="cpw"
                    class="form-control my-3 p-4"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <button class="btn1 mt-3 mb-5" type="submit">Register</button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <p>Have an account then <a href="/">Sign In</a></p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what I did wrong because it looks like it is working fine with your snippet but I don't know what you did different @Jeet Patel

Comment: happy to explaing. :) you just miss `</div>` at `<div class="col-lg-7 px-5 pt-5">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold py3">Registration Form</h1>........</div>`.

I just added it.

Comment: Where did you add the </div>

Comment: main div of username section is parenting all inputs because you forgot to close it befor start 'username' div part. so parant was controlling all input tags styling. it was minor mistake. I suggest you to use auto html syntax complition so it will not happen in futer.

Comment: Thank you I added that /div did wonders LOL  Thank you so much :)

Comment: cheers. I did some similar mistakes but in PHP. so we are the same. :)

Comment: @JeetPatel, please edit your post and add the explication in comment. Try to thing that other persons may read your answer later. Thank you and well done for you good answer

Comment: I will keep that in mind, I am pretty new to this community. Thank you for tip.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question this should help you.
You need to add crispy form tag on the top of the index page. To use crispy form tags, you need to install them first;

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

Then on the top of the index page (or any page where the form is present or use it in the base.html page);

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

Create your forms in a different file named as forms.py where you can create your forms from python classes.
Import these forms into the views.py file and transfer them to html pages as variables.
In html pages;

```
<form action=some_url>
{{ form | crispy }} <!-- here the form is the variable whose value is set to be the class which created form in forms.py -->
</form>
```

Comment: Also you should post some screen shots of the pages (registration and login to undestand question correctly)

Comment: I can't post screen shots so I have links sent to the pictures

Comment: I have not learned about for crispy think yet so I will hold off on that for now thanks a lot though :)

Comment: Got your question right. Crispy forms will also solve the problem.You should learn that as that is much easy and you have to write really less code than what you have already written.